# How to extract map keys from JSON in Power BI?

Tags: json, powerbi

I would like to have a list exported form JSON topo file used in Power BI - column JPT_nazwa_ .
[map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tSoB.png)

Is there any way to get this?

Here is the json file:
[Json file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QnaBmaNIdFtxxw2tWW0sBX_VCaiaIe7N/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We usually don't do homework here, so show us some effort first!

Comment: Hi, I understand. Actually it took me long time to get to this point - looking for correct geo data and convert to useful format.

Comment: How do you want to use the data in Power BI?

Comment: There is option to create Shape map using json file with conturs. I uploaded this already and want to get the keys to implement and link with data to visualize on this map.